# changing the default voice in android tts?

Tags: android

hi is there a way by which one can change the default voice (female) in the android tts? like if i want some other voice (male)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no. You could try using setPitch to make it deeper?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setPitch(float)