# Change default speech voice in text to speech by on screen option inside the app

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recording

I'm developing a text to speech app that required change default speech voice in android. how can i use child voice or female voice and other available voice in android those are free to use?? Can I load user voice as speech voice?? I want to give option of changing voice on main screen of app.

How Many other voice are available for android test to speech those are free to use, how I can use them??
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890911/android-tts-male-female-voice-change, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115299/changing-the-default-voice-in-android-tts, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362534/how-to-programmtically-change-tts-default-engine